# Using `C-n` and `C-p` to iterate as cycle in `find-file` instead of up/down arrow keys

Tags: isearch, history-variables

Following [answer related to “Open Recent” in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527436/2402577) indicates that

> After you press C-x C-f, press up and down to navigate the history of
>   opened files.

---

I have added following lines but they do not show cycle behavior like `up`, `down` arrow keys

It says: `beginning of history` or `end of defaults no next item`

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-n") 'next-history-element)
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-p") 'previous-history-element)
```

**[Q]** Instead of using `up` or `down` arrow keys, is it possible to use keybinding as `C-n`(down) and `C-p`(up) to iterate after typing `C-x C-f`?

Comment: I just fired up an emacs -Q. C-h k <down arrow> after C-x X-f shows 'next-line-or-history-element. So you're almost there. bind 'next-line-or-history-element and 'previous-line-or-history-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer** (just giving Fish):
Yes of course it is, this is Emacs.
Bound to `up` and `down` during `find-file` are the commands `previous-line-or-history-element` and `next-line-or-history-element`. So you should try to bind these functions to `C-n` and `C-p`.:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-n") #'next-line-or-history-element)
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-p") #'previous-line-or-history-element)
```

**Meta** (teaching how to fish):
Question: How did I know which function is bound? Answer: I used the built in help functions. You can always press `C-h k` and then the key to get the documentation of that keystroke. So I found out what the bound functions are.
Question: How can I see what key shortcuts are available, currently? Answer: press `C-h m` it shows you the current mode documentation and key shortcuts.

**Related**:
Get familiar with the emacs help system [here you can see available help commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Help-Summary.html#Help-Summary)

Consider using following packages (install them via MELPA and the package manager)

- [ivy swiper counsel](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) this enhances/replaces many default commands with more comfortable and autocompleting commands
- [helpful](https://github.com/Wilfred/helpful) a much improved help system

Comment: ah. nicely explained.

Comment: It work! but it does not act as cycle, I guess its is normal behavior. Ah when I press `C-h`, it deletes a character :/

Comment: @alper: See the Emacs manual, node [DEL Does Not Delete](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55803/using-c-n-and-c-p-to-iterate-as-cycle-in-find-file-instead-of-up-down-arro) for your question/problem about `C-h` deleting a char.